# Established functions

Tags: functions

Signum returns the sign of a number in the form of a number. Is there a function that returns the position in an *n*-tuple occupied by the greatest value of that *n*-tuple?

For example, for (5,6,3) it would return 2 because the maximum value is the 2nd in the 3-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can denote it $\text{arg max}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max.